# caretEnsemble fails when na.action=na.pass is included

Tags: r, machine-learning, na, r-caret

I want to create a ensemble model using the 'caretList' function in R package 'caretEnsemble'

When I include the code na.action = na.pass in my ensemble code, I get the error

```
"Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"
```

As far as I understand this error occurs when you try to use an R function as a object. But my code appears correct and I used the same code to successfully train separate models in R package "caret"

If I exclude na.action=na.pass, I get the error

```
"Error in na.fail.default(list(y = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,: missing values in object"
```

If I run the model on the dataset where I have excluded all the incomplete rows (where any observation has an na), it runs. 
My dataset has 19 (all numeric) predictor variables, 30905 rows (observations) with several na values in it (some variables up to 18 000 na's). So I do not want to only model with only complete rows.

My model code is as follows:

```
set.seed(1269)
    mycontrol<- trainControl(
      method="repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats = 5,
      savePredictions = "final",
      classProbs=TRUE,
      index = createResample(dat$y,25),
      summaryFunction=twoClassSummary
    )

model_list <- caretList(
  y~., data=dat,
  trControl=mycontrol,
  na.action = na.pass,
  methodList=c("ranger","gbm")
  )
```

I have checked the structure of the data. The predictor variable is a two-class factor and the response variables are all either numeric or integers. I have also used the same data to successfully train independent models in caret, so I doubt it is a problem with the data.

Does anyone have a possible solution for me? Thank you.

Edit: I made use of the function "knnImputation" in the R package "DMwR" to impute NA values before modelling, in stead of including this in the "preprocess" function/phase. Now my model is running. But I am still interested to find out why I had these errors.